Goldstone Theorem in Schwartz, follow-up
This is somewhat of a related question to
Goldstone theorem in Schwartz
and is related to equation 28.16 in Schwartz's QFT book.
One way to prove that
$$ \langle \Omega | J^\mu(x) | \pi(p) \rangle = i p^\mu F_\pi e^{-i p \cdot x} \tag{28.16}$$
for $$ \mathscr{L} = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \pi)^2 \tag{28.14}$$ is to show that $$ \langle \Omega | \pi(x) | \pi(p) \rangle = e^{-i p \cdot x} .$$ This can be done by using $$|\pi(p) \rangle = \pi(p) | \Omega \rangle$$ and expanding in canonical commutators/bashing it out. However, if we were to integrate out the $\sigma$ modes explicitly, we'd get terms in the Lagrangian that generically look like $$(\partial_\mu \pi \partial_\mu \pi)^2, (\partial_\mu \partial^\mu \pi)^2, \text{etc.},$$
which would change the form of the canonical momentum. Is eq. (28.16) still true even with these corrections? Is there a way to show this without using canonical quantization?
Relatedly, Schwartz says in equation 28.30 that because pions are Goldstone bosons, they satisfy $$\langle \Omega | J_\mu^{5a} (x) | \pi^b(p) \rangle = i p_\mu F_\pi e^{-ip\cdot x}\delta^{ab} \tag{28.30}$$ but he doesn't actually prove this using canonical quantization/etc. Is the same sort of canonical quantization calculation valid here? Is there a way to prove this relation for pions without using canonical quantization? And why does this relation imply that
$$J_\mu^{5a} = F_\pi \partial_\mu \pi^a ~?$$
